# Focus traversal between two tables in a Panel

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have two (5 * 1) tables to be shown as a single table on UI. How can I get a focus traversal mechanism for the two components(table) which mimics the behavior of single ( 5 * 2 ) table.

Comment: Why don't you simply create one table with 2 columns?

Comment: I can't! The current design doesn't support it and I need to this way. Why would I post this question otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom focus traversal Action. [Table Tabbing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/) shows you how to create a custom tabbing Action for a single table.

In your case I would guess the custom Action would require a List of tables you want to tab between. Then for each tab request you move to the next table. When you reach the last table you go the the first and incrment the row. The Action would need to be installed an all the tables.